# ETL - how to enter a website, input some paramenters and export a file (or web data) to database

Tags: web-scraping, etl

I'm looking for some recommendations:

I need to enter to a website, input some data, and export the file for that data to load into a database.

I've been trying to use tools for ETL such as Octoparse. the issue that I have is that with the ETL I know I can't replicate the "export to csv" that the website does, so I can take information from the tables shown, the problem with this is that the data is collapsed in the website. here an example:

[image]

in "1" I need to input from a to dates
the issue is that after filtering here, the tables are collapsed with and I have to open with "2"

I have the option to manually export the file as CSV by clicking "3" and later import this to a database, but actually it does take a some extra work. what type of ETL could I use to accomplish this activity?
the main goal is to export this data to a SQL database without manual intervention.

The website doesn't have an API to connect.

Comment: whats the url so I can test it out?

Comment: it's under a login gate, the website is trinks.com but info is not accesible without username and pass. if we chat I can show you (I sent an invite)

Comment: didn't get any invite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since there's no API or other means to fetch that directly, you can use Selenium to simulate the browser and click the buttons. This should log you in, change to the desired start date, filter, then export.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

# Enter you parameters
user = 'username@gmail.com'
pwd = 'password'
startDate = '01/03/2020'

# Open page
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe') #<-- put the path to chromedriver.exe on your machine here.
driver.get('https://www.trinks.com/BackOffice/Relatorios/Financeiro')

# Input username, password and click enter
driver.find_element_by_id("fEmail").send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_id("fSenha").send_keys(pwd)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[title="Entrar nos Trinks"]').click()


# Remove date and enter new start date and click filter
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'DataInicio')))
driver.find_element_by_id('DataInicio').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
driver.find_element_by_id('DataInicio').send_keys(Keys.DELETE);    
driver.find_element_by_id("DataInicio").send_keys(startDate)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[title="Filtrar"]').click()


# Click export and wait to allow it to start download
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[title="Exportar"]').click()
time.sleep(15)

# Close browser
driver.close()
```

Comment: before this I have never used python or selenium or beautiful soup, the speed in which you wrote this script made me gain interest about it, I'm eating manuals now and I'm really liking it!  very easy to use and understand, and a great tool for ETL (my ackground is in SSIS, SQL, SSRS, etc) and this is a great addition. thank you!